# Скрипт поиска файлов

Tags: php

Хотел бы написать рекурсивный скрипт поиска файлов, то есть из директории запуска на сервере рекурсивно искать по маске.

Comment: у вас че гугл удалили?? народ совсем уже обленился - в инете куча реализаций того что тебе именно нада

Comment: Но видимо решили не тратить время и написать сюда, чтобы скрипт за вас написали :) В чём вопрос то, обойти папки/подпапки, рекурсия, регулярное выражение не получается составить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php , обязательно должно помочь.